# Is there a way to run Flask server and store incoming data from a message broker at the same time?

Tags: json, api, flask, multiprocessing

I have an incoming stream of data from a message broker. The data is in JSON format. I also have RESTful API I built using Flask where I can get certain information. How can I run the server for the API and store the incoming data in a dictionary at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to using Redis to caching data from message broker follow key-value format.

Comment: But how do I do it while my server is running? I am able to do just one thing at a time. Threading isn't working since both the processes are non-terminating processes.